# What is the difference between NDK and SDK

Tags: android

I want to know the difference between Software Development Kit (SDK) and Native Development Kit(NDK) in android.

Comment: @MD this what I do and I come here :) So I m happy that Ankita asked the question !

Answer (score 14):

**- NDK**

> 1 ) NDK is a set of tools to compile C code to shared lib,
>        which you could use in your app - and that's all.
>
> 2) Enables legacy code re-use between iOS and Android platforms
>   Good for implementing CPU intensive operations that don't
>   allocate much memory like signal processing, physics simulations.

**- SDK**

> 1 ) SDK is the main development kit for Android apps - it contains
>   tools for Java and resources (png, xml) compiling, packaging to apk
>   file, installing, running and debugging them on a device, an emulator,
>   documentation, etc.
>
> 2 ) Java has superior memory management model  Superior threading
>   model Better exception handling model Rich set of libraries Superior
>   support for unicode characters.